# how to turn off "recording" in CoreAudio session?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm using the MoMu Audio Toolkit (http://momu.stanford.edu/toolkit/) to create a simple iPad-based musical instrument/teaching tool. It's been great, but just when I thought I'd got all the way through finalizing the first version of my app without so much as a hiccup using it, a small anomaly I noticed early on is coming back to bite me:

When switching to another application, the iPad status bar briefly flashes red and says "Recording" even though my app does not do any recording. Even worse, in iOS 7, if the operating system *thinks* the app is trying to record, it asks the user for permission to use the microphone. This is not acceptable behavior for a playback-only app (and App Store will reject).

I hoped the problem was simply that the toolkit's AudioSession initialization code was setting `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory` to `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` instead of to a playback-only category (`kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbientSound` or `kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback`). Changing that, however, does not seem to help.

```
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback; //kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
err = AudioSessionSetProperty( kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category );
```

Anybody familiar with this problem? What exactly triggers the "Recording" status on app-switch (and the permissions prompt in iOS7)?

Comment: Are you calling AudioSessionSetActive: and passing false when going to background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toolkit might be configuring the RemoteIO Audio Unit for full-duplex, instead of audio output only.  If so, find the audio unit port enables, and switch one to disable.  Or see if the toolkit has a switch to do that for you.

Comment: Yes, that was it! The toolkit was unconditionally setting the `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO` property. Thanks mucho!